# Mockito - separately verifying multiple invocations on the same method

Tags: java, mockito

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.atLeastOnce;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mockito;


public class MockitoTest {


    public static class TestMock {
        public void doIt(String s) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestMock mock = Mockito.mock(TestMock.class);
        mock.doIt("1");
        mock.doIt("2");

        ArgumentCaptor<String> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).doIt(argument.capture());
        System.out.println(argument.getValue());
        verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).doIt(argument.capture());
        System.out.println(argument.getValue());
    }
}
```

I expected this to print `1 2` but it instead prints `2 2`. It seems the '1' invocation is lost. Is there a way that I can verify that verifications happened with `1` and then `2`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can call [`ArgumentCaptor.getAllValues()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.16/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html#getAllValues()) instead of [`getValue()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.16/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html#getValue()). This will return all captured values:

> Returns all captured values. Use it when capturing varargs or when the verified method was called multiple times.

In this case, it will return a `List<String>` containing `1` and `2`.

The `getValue()` method only returns the last captured value:

> Returns the captured value of the argument.
>
> If the method was called multiple times then it returns the latest captured value

In your code, you can replace `atLeastOnce()` with the more precise `times(2)` since the mock was called 2 times. You don't need to have two distinct calls to `verify` to capture the arguments: Mockito will be able to capture all arguments passed to the mock with just one call.

```
TestMock mock = Mockito.mock(TestMock.class);
mock.doIt("1");
mock.doIt("2");

ArgumentCaptor<String> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
verify(mock, times(2)).doIt(argument.capture()); // verify that it was call 2 times and capture the values given

System.out.println(argument.getAllValues());
```

Answer (score 7):

Switch to `getAllValues()` from `getValues()`. It will return a list of all the captures it performs on your mock.

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).doIt(argument.capture());
System.out.println(argument.getAllValues().get(0));
verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).doIt(argument.capture());
System.out.println(argument.getAllValues().get(1));
```

Comment: Second call of verify is unnecessary as all arguments are captured in first call.

Answer (score 6):

What I actually needed in the end was in-order verification for incremental verification, using the calls() VerificationMode

```
public static class A {

    public void a(int x) {}

    public void b() {}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = mock(A.class);
    a.b();
    a.a(1);
    a.a(1);
    a.a(2);
    a.a(3);
    a.a(4);

    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(a);
    // Verifies [1,1]
    inOrder.verify(a, calls(2)).a(1);
    {
        // Verifies [2]
        ArgumentCaptor<Integer> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
        inOrder.verify(a, calls(1)).a(argument.capture());
        System.out.println(argument.getAllValues());
    }
    {
        // Verifies [3,4]
        ArgumentCaptor<Integer> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
        inOrder.verify(a, calls(2)).a(argument.capture());
        System.out.println(argument.getAllValues());
    }
}
```